# how to pass a variable to a layout page PHP

Tags: php

Hello im using two files 1. layout.html.php(for all the HTML code) 2.layout.php(for all the PHP code)
Im trying to send a variable from the layout.php to layout.html.php file

The variable is equal to a list of all jobs from a database table 
See code below

I want to use this list of jobs in a unordered list as links in layout.html.php file

I would appreciate any help i can get with this

CODE FOR LAYOUT.HTML.PHP

```
<li>Jobs
<ul>

<?php                   
    foreach ($jobs as $job){?>
                <li><a href= "/<?= $job['name']?>?id=<?=$job['id']?>"><?= $job['name']?> </a></li>

            <?php }?>

                </ul>
```

CODE FOR LAYOUT.PHP

```
<?php 
require '../loadTemplate.php';

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM job');
    $stmt->execute();
    $jobs= $stmt->fetchAll();

    $templateVars = ['stmt' => $jobs];

    $output = loadTemplate('../templates/layout.html.php',['stmt' => $jobs]);

    require  '../templates/layout.html.php';

    ?>
```

Comment: Enable error reporting and see what that reveals.

Comment: The erorr im getting is Notice: Undefined variable: jobs in /srv/layout.html.php on line 36
SImply because the variable isnt being sent to the html.php page

Comment: Entirely depends on how `loadTemplate()` works. Presumably that's the function generating your output from the `layout.html.php` file. Unclear as to why you're also `require`-ing the layout file, and unclear what `$templateVars` is supposed to do in the above, and why you're sending `$jobs` to it under the key `stmt`. Figure these out, and you may find clarity. :)

Comment: Your error is being triggered with the `loadTemplate('../templates/layout.html.php' aftermath, since the `$jobs` variable will not be available in the function's context.

Comment: ive tried removing it but it didnt quite work as expected

Answer (score 0):

If in a file A you got the variable X:

```
<?php
    $frase = "abcdef";
?>
```

Then if you want to use the same variable in another file you can use:

```
<?php
    include('A.php');
    echo $frase;
?>
```

There is other ways to do that. You can also use the Session, cookies, or just pass in the url.

In my case, I like to do in that way: 
I have a page home.php. In that page I represents a consult. So, in home.php I got:

```
<?php
     include 'php/db.php'
     $result = BuscaDados();
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
         // here you get all lines
     }

?>
```

In db.php I got a implementation of my functions that return the consult. Try it out.

Comment: i tried including that file however that didnt quite work

Comment: You just wanna do a select in your database and get the result ok your page, correct?

Comment: correct which i have done here in layout.php 
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM job');
    $stmt->execute();
    $jobs= $stmt->fetchAll();